# How to display only hidden files in directory using ls command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls

I am trying to display the hidden files from a directory using the ls command alone, except for `.` and `..`.

```
ls -lAd .*
```

But the command returns `.` and `..` directory names also in the output . What's wrong in this command even though I mentioned "A" option with ls .

Comment: `.` and `..` are also hidden files

Comment: Your wildcard matches `.` and `..` as well.

Comment: @TristanT It's the `.*` that is the problem. `-A` shows `.whatever` but skips `.` and `..` [as opposed to `-a` which includes them]. I'm not sure `ls` can do it alone. I'd do `ls -lAd | grep '^[.]'`. Adjust the `grep` suitably for the `ls -l` format

Comment: I usually to this with `ls -la .??*`. That ignored the directory entries.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`GLOBIGNORE`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#GLOBIGNORE) internal variable.

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=.:.. ls -ld .*
```

Comment: thanks @anishsane . But if I set it like inside a script do I have to unset the GLOBIGNORE in some way before exiting from the script ?

Comment: Assuming that you execute the script & not source it, you don't need to unset the variable.

Comment: I took the freedom and edited the post. Now the variable will be only visible to ls, not to the script

Answer (score 1):

This is here for reference but the answer is given by [@anishsane below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37850947/887539).

Your glob is wrong:

```
.*
```

will be expanded to `.`, and `..`. You can either change the glob to something like:

```
.??*
```

but this will not match hidden files like: `.a`, `.b`. Or `.[^.]*` but that will not match files like `..a`, `..b`, combining both might be an option:

```
ls -lAd .[^.]*  ..?*
```

But that will most likely yeild: `ls: error: ..?* no such file or directory`. Enabling nullglob will prevent this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
ls -lAd .[^.]*  ..?*
```

This will however expand to `ls -lAd` if no hidden files are in the directory, which will show current working directory (`.`)

Alternative you can pipe the output from `ls` to `awk`, but that will most likely get rid of the colors:

```
ls -lA | awk '$9 ~ /^\./'
```

Also consider reading: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: even with `nullglob`, if there are no hidden files or directories, the 2 globs `.[^.]*` & `..?*` will expand to nothing (empty string). This will execute just `ls -lAd` command, giving `.` as result.

Comment: @anishsane You are correct. Thanks for noticing me! I will keep my answer as a reference but I can see you have provided a better solution :-)

Comment: I realized a bit late - with nullglob set, your or mine - both answers will behave the same. So, with nullglob, we should pass them to some other construct, like `echo .[^.]* ..?*` or `for f in .[^.]* ..?*`. Without nullglob set, both our answers will print an error, saying `file .[^.]* ..?* not found` or `file .* not found`...

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -Al --ignore="[^.]*"
```

where you ignore all files and directories which NOT start with a `.`

**Extra**: You can call this for any directory, which comes in handy if you use it as an alias in your .bashrc

```
alias lsh='ls -Al --ignore="[^.]*"'
```

Just do

```
lsh /path/directory
```